# Any editor with CTRL+R binding for compiling LaTeX

Tags: shortcut-keys, latex, text-editor, text-processing, usability

I just had to replace my OSX with Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to find ways to get Textmate's capabilities to some text-editor:

- CMD+R compiles the document in Textmates and let's you choose different options if failed; Is there any editor with has keybinding to this kind of function?
- CMD+/ allows to comment any document type in Textmate; this is very useful in writing code; Does Ubuntu have any program which can do this?

I have tried to use Gedit but the problem is the configuration is mostly visual. 
I just want to have configs in some file and terminal so I can have easy integration to my other Ubuntu machines.

How can you use some text-editor better for text-editing in Ubuntu?

Comment: I use TeXstudio and the shortcuts are customizable under `Options->Configure TeXstudio->Shortcuts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Geany IDE. Some drawbacks but central things work like Search in Files, ... LaTeX component found for the IDE. I think the keybinding can be customized there.